# How to ignore the HTTP cache for CDN images?

Tags: http, caching

I am requesting bunch of CDN images on my website.
In the response headers, I got the following cache policy:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public, no-transform
```

meaning that the HTTP cache will have them stored for one year.
However, one specific image changes quite often on the CDN and I would need it to change on my site often.
Triggering refreshes work as it requests ressources ignoring `max-age` but I can't see myself asking my users to do this.

What are my options here ? I was thinking about requesting these specific assets with a timestamp query parameter:

```
?t=1990090151555
```

That would basically disable the cache for these images.
Is that the best way to do this ?

Comment: Not sure about "the best" but it is the classical way of cache avoiding. I suppose that "the best" would be to actually fix the issue on the CDN side. Why is there such a big max age to begin with? Can you configure the CDN to use etags instead?

Answer (score 0):

I've used this solution and it didn't trouble me.
I've also looked up for a CDN with this possible parameter configurable but i didn't find anyone.